# Linux can't determine MIME type for 3GP, 3GPP2, etc. files?

Tags: linux, centos, mime, 3gp

When I run

```
    file -bi 'filename'
```

in CentOS for 3GP, 3GPP2, etc. files, the return value is blank. For other files such as JPEG, GIF, MPEG, etc, the command returns the correct MIME type. Why is this so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because the magic number for these video file type is not defined

you can take  look on

man file

http://linux.die.net/man/1/file

Comment: @tundoopani In the given man page: `The environment variable MAGIC can be used to set the default magic number file name. If that variable is set, then file will not attempt to open $HOME/.magic . file adds ".mime" and/or ".mgc" to the value of this variable as appropriate.` So set `$MAGIC` or create a `$HOME/.magic` file.

Comment: @glglgl Wow, this seems like a research project all by itself - adding magic number support is *not* trivial!

Comment: futhermore, it seems that there *are* magic numbers defined for various video formats including the ones I am trying to recognize, but it's *still* not recognizing them!